# Red dots in typescript source file in Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, typescript

I want to debug a typescript file in Google Chrome, but for some reason I see weird red dots. See image.

Has anyone encountered that?
I've tried to change encoding of that file to UTF-8 but it did not help.

How to fix it?

[image]

It happens in Chrome only (both Standard and Canary versions). IE and Firefox behaves ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file appears to have been encoded using UTF-16 but is being interpreted as UTF-8. Each of the red dots represents a null byte which is supposed to be part of a two-byte character in UTF-16 but is its own character in UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, that could be it.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what has caused it, but the problem is gone.

This is what I've done:
- Save the file in UTF-8 (just for sure)
- Change something in the file
- Rebuild solution