# Laravel 5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (red dots)

Tags: javascript, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I'm new with Laravel and have installed a new project succesfull. My Laravel project is based on composer(https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation#installing-laravel)

Now I get some errors while loading some .js files. The error is known by me and i've searched the whole internet to find a solution for me, because I used composer install instead of vagrant installer.

The error:

�HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: laravel.dev:8000 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: application/javascript 
Content-Length: 97163

[Laravel javascript red dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj41B.png)

As u can see above, there are red dots in a .js files with some header description in it.

I found many solutions, but all of them are about vagrant (homestead) or apache, but I can't find any of that files in my computer. Of course I have found the apache config file and added the EnableSendfile off , but that doesn't work, because my laravel project runs on php artisan serve.

So is there someone who knows the solution for my situation?

Comment: **�HTTP/1.1 200 OK Host: laravel.dev:8000 Connection: close Content-Type: application/javascript Content-Length: 97163** - This is not an error, thats a response, and a successful (200) one at that. How are you serving/requesting your javascript? Have you followed [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/frontend)?

Comment: check your encoding http://stackoverflow.com/a/30578907/4986182

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change in ./server.php. May be this will resolve the issue.

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
   return false;
}
```

to

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
ob_end_clean ();
   return false;
}
```